# FormRecognizer Pricing Tier S0 : Free monthly allowance?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

My azure subscription costs mention some free allowance my `FormRecognizer` resource (pricing tier `S0`)

[image]

I obviously won't complain about it (if it's true) but the pricing page is not really explicit about this free allowance mechanism :
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/form-recognizer/

Now I haven't been able to find the answer on the doc but if I have two distinct `FormRecognizer` (pricing tier `S0`) resources. Does it meen that I get 500 free pages per month **per `FormRecognizer` resource** or is it a **global** allowance ?

Comment: usually any free tiers are per subscription. Otherwise people would just create a new resource every time ;)

Answer (score 0):

@silent , you're absolutely right.
Here's MSFT answer :

> Based on the Free Azure Services offer, the Form Recogniser includes 500 pages S0 tier total monthly allowance for all resources used/created. This means that if you have two form of recognized resource, your allowance will be 250 pages S0 tier for each of them.